# Dynamically change style of a WMS layer already loaded

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, geoserver, wms

I want to create a panel where the user will be able to change the style of a selected layer.

For vector layer, there is no problem updating the ol.style config, but I don't really know how to proceed for an ImageWMS layer.

[Based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891664/dynamically-style-a-wms-layer-with-javascript-from-geoserver), I'm guessing I need to add a new SLD file to the layer and refresh it, but how can this be achieved with OL3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for

http://opendem.info/ol3/wms_sld.html